# How can i remove/delete from a richTextBox a specific text line?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried this code:

```
private void RemoveLines(List<string> Keywords)
        {
            string NewText = "";
            String regex = string.Empty;
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { NewText = richTextBox1.Text; }));
            Regex MyRegex = null;
            foreach (string keyword in Keywords)
            {
                regex = String.Format(@"^.*\W{0}\W.*$",keyword);
                MyRegex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
                NewText = MyRegex.Replace(NewText, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            //Remove blank lines
            NewText = Regex.Replace(NewText, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { richTextBox1.Text = NewText; }));
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { richTextBox1.Refresh(); }));
        }
```

And the removeExtrenals function:

```
private List<string> removeExternals(List<string> externals)
        {
            if(!LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
            {
                return externals;
            }
            List<string> keywords = LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl];
            List<int> indices = new List<int>();
            foreach(string keyword in keywords)
            {
                //Accumulate a list of the indices of the items that match.
                indices = indices.Concat(externals.Select((v, i) => v.Contains(keyword) ? i : -1)).ToList();
            }
            //Filter out the -1s, grab only the unique indices.
            indices = indices.Where(i => i >= 0).Distinct().ToList();
            //Filter out those items that match the keyword(s) related to mainUrl.
            externals = externals.Where((v, i) => !indices.Contains(i)).ToList();
            return externals;
        }
```

And im calling the removelines and the removeexternals in this function:

```
RemoveLines(removeExternals(webSites));
```

In removeExternals after using breakpoint i see two sites that are no containing google(the keyword im using for the example) so from 18 url's i should see in the richTextBox only 16 url's
I used a breakpoint also in the removelines function no exceptions but i see all the url's in the richTextBox.

Comment: does it have to be a textbox? it would be much easier with listbox or a grid if editing is needed

Comment: It would be helpful if you can please put more details on what is your exact requirement by giving a short example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:
I added some random data for testing..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(@"Loading The Url:   http://www.blogger.com/?tab=wj... Failed ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(@"Loading The Url:   http://www.google.co.il/intl/iw/options/... Done  ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(@"Loading The Url:   http://www.xyz.com/?tab=wj... Failed ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(@"Loading The Url:   http://www.abc.com/?tab=wj... Done ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(@"Loading The Url:   http://www.so.com/?tab=wj... Failed ");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        keys.Add("xyz");
        keys.Add("abc");
        RemoveLines(keys);
    }
```

and here's the code for `RemoveLines` Method..

```
private void RemoveLines(List<string> Keywords)
    {
        String regex = string.Empty;
        string NewText = richTextBox1.Text;            
        Regex MyRegex = null;
        foreach (string keyword in Keywords)
        {
            regex = String.Format(@"^.*\W{0}\W.*$",keyword);
            MyRegex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            NewText = MyRegex.Replace(NewText, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        //Remove blank lines
        NewText = Regex.Replace(NewText, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline); 
        richTextBox1.Text = NewText;
        richTextBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Luftwaffe i tried your code and its not working for some reason i will update my question.

Comment: @DanielLip If your intention was to delete lines from your `RichTextBox` which contain specific keywords (as your question heading says) then the above code will definitely work. Or is your requirement different ?

Comment: No Lutwaffe thats what i needed. Ok Thanks i will check it more now. Maybe i put the removal line in a bad place in the test function. Thanks.